# jsforce logout functionality

Tags: node.js, jsforce, lwc-oss, node-salesforce

In one of my node project, I am using jsforce oauth2 to connect to Salesforce. This is working nicely. Below is the code I am using for logout functionality. This is also working fine without any issue. But next time when I am trying to login again, it doesn't ask user to put username/password to verify the oauth2. Instead it's directly logged into with the previous login. I am adding access_token, refresh_token as a scope.

Logout code:

```
let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    oauth2: oauth2,
    accessToken : req.body.accessToken,
    instanceUrl : req.body.logoutURL
  });
  conn.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    // now the session has been expired.
    console.log('successfully logged out !!');
    req.body.accessToken = '';
    req.body.logoutURL = '';
    res.end();
  });
```

This code prints successfully logged out. But it doesn't invalidate the session in actual.

Comment: Are you caching the accessToken and refreshToken in your session somehow? Perhaps because you have refresh_token in the scope, it is simply performing a refresh of the access_token?  Perhaps if you reset accessToken and refreshToken it will.

Comment: I am storing accesstoken and refreahtoken in localstorage. But from client side when user clicks on logout button it deletes all the localstorage and call jsforce logout api.